# Socket.io getting a socket every milisecond/frame

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, socket.io, p5.js

My problem started when I wanted to solve a bug of my game. I'm using socket.io, for my multiplayer game. It is a 2D shooter. It's all working fine on the client side. I'm using p5.js, and I'm just sending all the positions of all the bullets, and showing them. When I'm chaning the tab, because I'm moving the bullets in the client, all the bullets that I shot, stop. So, I want to move the bullets in the server. So, I get a socket when I shoot, with the initial position of the bullet, the direction, and the id. I want to move them by the direction, then send them to all the players, every second. But, I need to do it in the newConnection(socket) function, where all the socket.on() are located, so, it is possible to get a socket every frame, without any corelation with the client? Like, every milisecond, or something like that, to get a socket, from the server, like socket.on("something"){} then the function, and I'm getting the socket every milisecond, not from the client. It is possible? Then, how?

Comment: Well bullets travel in a straight line so why not send/emit the position from the shot being taken, if something within it's path is to stop it I'm sure you can deal with that client-side rather than having to track every pixel/movement of something that you know will be travelling in a straight line.....

Comment: I just want to know the thing with the socket that I'm getting every milisecond from the server, I like how my game works, I need the part with socket.io only.

Comment: Do you have websockets setup and in use already or are you asking how to use them?